# Azure Queue Trigger not firing when deployed

Tags: azure, queue, azure-functions

I am new to Azure and most cloud technologies but I am trying to learn. Recently I created a queue trigger in Visual Studio Code and I ran a HTTP trigger that sent messages to the queue and created a queue trigger that printed it out to logs. When I deploy this to Azure I am able to call the HTTP trigger to put items in the queue, but for some reason the queue trigger is not firing. Have you guys encountered this problem?

When I run it locally it seems to trigger but when I deploy it nothing happens.

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4diQS.png)

[queue trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnxJi.png)

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the queue trigger will be triggered by the storage queue? Have you configured the queue trigger correct? Any way, please show your code and related files such as function.json or local.settings.json